# How to create separate list for each property in class

Tags: c#

I have below class,

```
public class class1
{
  public int prop1 {get; set;}
  public string prop2 {get; set;}
  public bool prop3 {get; set;}
}

public class class2
{
   public int prop1 {get; set;}
   public List<string> prop2 {get; set;}
}

Now, for each property in class1 i need to build List<class2>.
```

Can you please let me know, how to accomplish this in c# 4.0?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you please be more specific

Comment: You can use a T4 template. Unless you simply mean "construct a collection at runtime" instead of "add a collection as a property to the type"

Comment: Dynamically i need to build List<class2> for each property in class1

Comment: @Jeron Can you please provide me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this C# newish "dynamic" keyword and the ExpandoObject, but dynamically creating generic list of dynamic type is pretty tricky.

I think this should work tho:

```
        dynamic myDynamicClass = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var prop in typeof (Foo).GetProperties()) {
            Type[] typeArgs = {prop.GetType()};
            var listImplementationType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            var myList = Activator.CreateInstance(listImplementationType);
            myDynamicClass[prop.Name] = myList;    
        }
```